# Android.mk syntax issue

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

I got a simple problem.

Here's  my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libandroidgameengine
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/ \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../interface/ \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/Render \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/Utils

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  # Core
                    ../src/Engine.cpp \

                    # Rendering
                    ../src/Render/RenderManagerImpl.cpp \

                    # Utils
                    ../src/Utils/LogManagerImpl.cpp \

                    # Memory
                    ../src/Memory/MemoryManagerImpl.cpp \
                    ../src/Memory/malloc.c

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DSTRUCT_MALLINFO_DECLARED
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lGLESv2 -llog
```

I keep getting "Android.mk:11 *** commands commence before first target" Error. I know it has something to do with the way I structured the source files (with hashtags to symbolize specific parts of the engine) but I do not understand how it is actually supposed to look like. Any hints?
    include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add comments into a variable definition in Make.

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  # Core
                    ../src/Engine.cpp \

...
```

Makefile syntax is line-based, thus in the code above parser treats only the first line as variable assignment (effectively it sets `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` to empty string). The second line is parsed as independent statement, in your case as a recipe (because of leading tabs).

Try removing comments from variable definition:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ../src/Engine.cpp \
    ../src/Render/RenderManagerImpl.cpp \
    ../src/Utils/LogManagerImpl.cpp \
    ../src/Memory/MemoryManagerImpl.cpp \
    ../src/Memory/malloc.c
```

Or split it using append operator and leaving comments outside:

```
# Core
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../src/Engine.cpp

# Rendering
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../src/Render/RenderManagerImpl.cpp

# Utils
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../src/Utils/LogManagerImpl.cpp

# Memory
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    ../src/Memory/MemoryManagerImpl.cpp \
    ../src/Memory/malloc.c
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have no spaces after a backslashes, also I am not sure if adding blank lines / comments between backslash ended lines is OK

Comment: I've made sure there is no space after backslash. Also, Surely you must be able to have commented-lines..?

Comment: space after '\' was my problem. Ty!